# Calling a python file via "nickname"

Tags: python, terminal

I have a python file called test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
import sys

#called when file called                                                        
print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

And I can call this file using `python test.py test` and it will print to the terminal correctly.

I wish to use a "nickname" (I know wrong word but not sure what it is) to call this file such as: `<nickname> test` and it do the same thing - how would I go about this?

An example would be I can type `emacs test.py` and it knows what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: yes :) cheers for the help, got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an alias (not a nickname ;) ) in Linux using `alias aliasname='commands to type'`. As such you could create an alias for your Python code with the code below.

```
alias nickname='python /path/to/dir/test.py'
```

You can then run it with `nickname test`. Note that you'll need to provide the full path to the file on the off-chance that you change directories. 'nickname' can obviously be anything you choose.

You'll need to add this alias to `.bashrc` or similar (depending on your system) so it's created everything you open your terminal otherwise it will only be usable in your current terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the symlink to python as someothername:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/someothername /usr/bin/python
```

Other way could be:

create env variable as

```
export someothername=python
```

Call as

```
$someothername args
```